# FIFO with one READER and multiple WRITER in BASH/SH

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, fifo

I have one named pipe (FIFO) say : 'MY_FIFO'

One process reads the fifo from multiple processes to get instructions.

(1) reader bash script:

```
while read LINE < 'MY_FIFO'
do
 # process line
done
```

(many) writer bash script:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  INSTRUCTION = # get an instruction
  echo $INSTRUCTION > 'MY_FIFO'
done
```

This works fine to pass instructions to the reader when we have 1 writer or that the writers don't write at the same time. But if we have many writers writing at the same time, the reader gets the first message from whoever was the very first to write to the FIFO, and then hangs waiting for input instead of fetching the next instruction.

What happens behind the scene that prevents me from having multiple writers write to the same fifo?
Are they overwriting each other's instructions?

Is there a way for me to test that the reader is ready to read from fifo before writing to the fifo?

Comment: Would be able to create a real [MCVE]?

Comment: Not really a bash or sh question specifically; this is a problem with FIFO semantics, you'd have it writing the same code in C too.

Comment: (note, for purposes of determining what constitutes "the same code", that when you exit the code that a redirection applies to, the file handle is explicitly closed, and an entirely new file handle is opened next time you enter that code block).

Comment: ...anyhow, one easy way to address this _without_ changing much would be to have a `flock`-style exclusive lock that needs to be held before any writer opens the file.

Comment: @willer2k, ...btw, as an aside, note that all-caps variable names are designated by the POSIX specification for variables that modify shell or system utility behavior, whereas variable names with at least one lower-case character are reserved "for application use", meaning they're guaranteed not to overwrite something that modifies shell behavior. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a namespace (setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: Very easily achieved with **Redis** by the way. Write to fifo from shell with `redis-cli LPUSH` and read from fifo with `redis-cli BRPOP`. Accepts timeouts. Works across networks not just on a single host. Has clients for C/C++, Python, PHP, Ruby...

Comment: Tangentially, `while [ 1 ]` is a bewilderingly concise articulation of all the common misunderstandings about `[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that when the writer has written its message, it closes the pipe and then your reader will exit that loop. You will also get garbled messages in the pipe when more than one process writes at the same time.

You could try something this instead. It uses `flock` to lock the pipe while writing to it:

**reader**

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ 1 ]]
do
    IFS= read -r LINE < MY_FIFO
    echo reader got "$LINE"
done
```

**writers** - Note that this opens the pipe first, then waits for the lock to succeed and finally writes the message:

```
#!/bin/bash

# getting instructions from stdin for demo purposes
while IFS= read -r INSTRUCTION
do
    echo Sending "$INSTRUCTION"

    # advisory lock of the pipe when writing
    flock MY_FIFO echo "$INSTRUCTION" > MY_FIFO
done
```

Optional **writers** - This creates a lockfile and does not open the fifo until the lock is actually held.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r INSTRUCTION
do
    echo Sending "$INSTRUCTION"
    {
         flock 9
         echo "$INSTRUCTION" > MY_FIFO
    } 9> MY_FIFO.lck
done
```

Comment: That's opening `MY_FIFO` for output _before_ `flock` runs, since redirections take place prior to `exec` of the target command.

Comment: Consider instead `exec {lock_fd}>MY_FIFO.lck; flock -x "$lock_fd"; echo "$INSTRUCTION" >MY_FIFO; exec {lock_fd}>&-` -- that way writers don't touch the FIFO itself at all until after they hold the lock. (Can manually allocate a FD if compatibility with bash before 4.1 is needed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I haven't fixed it but I'm thinking - does it matter if it opens the file first since it won't write until it has the lock?

Comment: Good question. Honestly, I'm aiming for maximal predictability here -- having only one writer _have the file open at a time_ means the reader will explicitly block on the open operation until a specific writer has the file open, and ensures that there will be a time period between writers when there's nothing on the write side so the reader can get an EOF; thus, the synchronization is easier to reason about.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do agree. I'll add an option.

Comment: Is `$lock_fd> MY_FIFO.lck` legal syntax? I don't recognize it, and http://shellcheck.net/ certainly doesn't like it at all.

Comment: ...anyhow, a full subshell seems a bit like overkill; just having a regular curly-brace code block with a redirection to the lockfile in it will still close the FD (and thus the lock) when the block exits, and won't impact variable scope or slow things down for the `fork()`. That is: `{ flock -x 9; echo "$INSTRUCTION" >MY_FIFO; } 9>MY_FIFO.lck`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How odd ... putting `9>` there works in that shell checker but not `${lock_fd}>`. My bash must be pimped somehow because it likes it fine :-) ... and I fixed the subshell thing.

Comment: Just `{lock_fd}>`, no `$` before the curly brace, for automatic FD assignment. But you don't want to use that syntax for a block-scoped redirection, since it doesn't (or at least, didn't when it was first added) close the FD when the block exits. (I complained to upstream, and was told it was a feature, not a bug).

Comment: The lock worked! Can i ask why @CharlesDuffy recommends flock -x instead of the flagless usage in the answer (flock 9 vs flock -x 9)?

Comment: @willer2k, the flagless usage is actually the more portable approach (since there exist versions of `flock` that don't support `-x`), stick with it. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm `{lock_fd}>` doesn't work in my environment - but neither does `${flock_fd}>` now. I think I'm a bit tired :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help @TedLyngmo and Charles!

Comment: @TedLyngmo, ...`{lock_fd}>` is a bash 4.1 feature IIRC (could maybe be 4.3), but it's not expected to work with versions that aren't fairly recent.

Comment: @willer2k You're welcome! Btw, `-x` is the default. I didn't know the flagless was more portable but, great :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Odd. I'm on 5.0.17(1) and [this](https://pastebin.com/1VkBRtZY) doesn't work while the code in the answer does - I must mess something up here ... :-/

Comment: `{lock_fd}>file` modifies `lock_fd` to have an automatically-allocated previously-free file descriptor, instead of using the value already in the variable, so it's not quite equivalent to the old operation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahhhh... I see. Many thanks for the help!