# Writing from multiple processes launched via xargs to the same fifo pipe causes lines to miss

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency, xargs, mkfifo

I have a script where I parallelize job execution while monitoring the progress. I do this using `xargs` and a named fifo pipe. My problem is that I while `xargs` performs well, some lines written to the pipe are lost. **Any idea what the problem is?**

For example the following script (basically my script with dummy data) will produce the following output and hangs at the end waiting for those missing lines:

```sh
$ bash test2.sh 
Progress: 0 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 0 in separate process
Progress: 1 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 1 in separate process
Progress: 2 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 2 in separate process
Progress: 3 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 3 in separate process
Progress: 4 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 4 in separate process
Progress: 5 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 5 in separate process
DEBUG: Processed data 6 in separate process
DEBUG: Processed data 7 in separate process
DEBUG: Processed data 8 in separate process
Progress: 6 of 99
DEBUG: Processed data 9 in separate process
Progress: 7 of 99
##### Script is hanging here (Could happen for any line) #####
```

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

printStateInLoop() {
  local pipe="$1"
  local total="$2"
  local finished=0

  echo "Progress: $finished of $total"
  while true; do
    if [ $finished -ge $total ]; then
      break
    fi

    let finished++
    read line <"$pipe"
      # In final script I would need to do more than just logging
    echo "Progress: $finished of $total"
  done
}

processData() {
  local number=$1
  local pipe=$2

  sleep 1 # Work needs time
  echo "$number" >"$pipe"
  echo "DEBUG: Processed data $number in separate process"
}
export -f processData

process() {
  TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
  PROGRESS_PIPE="$TMP_DIR/progress-pipe"
  mkfifo "$PROGRESS_PIPE"

  DATA_VECTOR=($(seq 0 1 99)) # A bunch of data
  printf '%s\0' "${DATA_VECTOR[@]}" | xargs -0 --max-args=1 --max-procs=5 -I {} bash -c "processData \$@ \"$PROGRESS_PIPE\"" _ {} &

  printStateInLoop "$PROGRESS_PIPE" ${#DATA_VECTOR[@]}
}

process
rm -Rf "$TMP_DIR"
```

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740536/read-from-n-pipes-from-one-process-in-parallel) I got the suggestion to switch to `while read line; do … done < "$pipe"` (function below) instead of `while true; do … read line < "$pipe" … done` to not close the pipeline on every line read. This reduces the frequency of the problem but still it happens: Some Lines are missing and sometimes a `xargs: bash: terminated by signal 13`.

```
printStateInLoop() {
  local pipe="$1"
  local total="$2"
  local finished=0

  echo "Progress: $finished of $total"
  while [ $finished -lt $total ]; do
    while read line; do
      let finished++
      # In final script I would need to do more than just logging
      echo "Progress: $finished of $total"
    done <"$pipe"
  done
}
```

*A lot of people on SO suggested to use [parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) or [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) for doing this. Sadly those tools aren't available on the very limited target platform. Instead my script is based on `xargs`.*

Comment: Have you considered having each writer obtain a lock on the pipe before writing to the pipe?  a google search on `bash linux flock write pipe` brings up several hints including a promising looking answer to [FIFO with single READER and multiple WRITERS in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64486022)

Comment: There is no interlocking on writes to the pipe. Quite possible events will get overwritten. Maybe you need to interlock the processes (flock?). Or write each to a separate pipe and gather the results

Comment: Thank you. That indeed solved the problem. I have already searched for a file lock mechanism but obviously did not use the right search terms.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as pointed out by @markp-fuso and @Dale) was to create a file lock.

Instead of:

```sh
echo "$number" >"$pipe"
```

I now use `flock` to create/wait for a lock first:

```sh
flock "$pipe.lock" echo "$number" >"$pipe"
```